Вопрос насчёт сочетания библиотек aiogram и art
Я создал функцию fn, которая принимает текстовое сообщение и с помощью библиотеки art преобразует его в текст и отправляет пользователю бота. Всё отлично работает со многими сообщениями, однако, когда пользователь вводит сообщения с некоторыми символами, например с буквами x или k, то бот ничего не отвечает, а в терминал выводится такое сообщение, но программа продолжает работать
import art
@dp.message(F.text)
async def fn(message: types.Message):
    art_answer = art.text2art(message.text)
    await message.reply(
        f'\n<code>{art_answer}</code>',
        parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML
    )


Не понимаю что делать

Может быть проблема в parse_mode?

В букве x присутствуют символы > и <, которые имеют особый смысл в html-разметке, поэтому перед запихиванием в html их надо экранировать (хотя я не в курсе, нормально ли телеграм воспринимает экранированные символы)

Как вариант - использовать не html формат вывода, а markdown

Но тогда появляется ещё больше неудобств.  ) Но спасибо. Зато узнал какие ещё есть parse_mode'ы.

andreymal, огромное спасибо! Хочу спросить: как Вам повысить рейтинг? Я плохо разбираюсь в этом сайте

Вот так выглядит правильный код:
import art
@dp.message(F.text)
async def fn(message: types.Message):
    art_answer = html.escape(art.text2art(message.text))
    await message.reply(
        f'\n<code>{art_answer}</code>',
        parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML
    )

Выражаю благодарность andreymal за правильный ответ на поставленный вопрос!
